# How to make HostListener for scroll work?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a `window:scroll` listener but when scrolling nothing happens

What I've tried so far:

**using `host` inside component decorator**

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    'window:scroll' : 'onWindowScroll($event)'
  },
  ...
)
export class PageWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  public onWindowScroll(event: Event): void {
    console.log('scrolled');
  }
  ...
}
```

**using `HostListener` inside component decorator**

```
export class PageWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  public onWindowScroll(event: Event): void {
    console.log('scrolled');
  }
  ...
}
```

**I also tried using it in an attribute directive but it didn't work either**

Neither will trigger the `console log`. I've searched for similar questions in SO but even though my code is essentially the same it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Using host inside component decorator**

it should be:

```
'(window:scroll)' : 'onWindowScroll($event)'
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/40HBOc96EcO0L4CMqDef)**

**Using HostListener inside component decorator**
Your syntax looks correct

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
public onWindowScroll(event: Event): void {
  console.log('scrolled');
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/b13rlzhq2C7Lwmoyjw0s?p=preview)**

You can also make sure that your component has scroll. In my examples i imitate scroll via:

```
styles: [`
    :host {
      display: block;
      height: 2000px;
    }
`]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the plunker examples. Unfortunately it still not working. I'm thinking it might be an issue with `ViewEncapsulation` I have it set to `none` in some of my parent components, you think this might cause it to not work?

Comment: No, i don't think so. You need to provide plunker to reproduce it

Comment: I'll try, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Interesting enough I cannot reproduce it on plunker. I also get no errors or warning on my console. I'll sleep on it, thanks for the help. I'm marking it answered because I know that's the correct answer and it's more than likely something in my code.

Answer (score 1):

My team and I recently ran into this issue. Our solution was to use angular's Renderer to set a listener for the 'scroll' event on the elementRefs parentNode.

```
`constructor(
  private _renderer: Renderer,
  private _elementRef: ElementRef
) {
  this._renderer.listen(this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode, 
   'scroll', (event) => {
      // do stuff with the event
  });
}`
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit. I'm new to angular.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I was able to out why HostListener wasn't working, I am using angular/material component library and I overrode the md-sidenav-layout height with 100vh and it didn't like that.